# What is the logic behind this assignment: understanding in-place assignment operations in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, reference, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

I have two fairly simple codes that give different answer. I understand it is due to the reference shared but I am not very clear what exactly happens in the 2nd case

```py
a = np.ones(5)
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
a=np.add(a, 1, out=a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

> [out]:
>
> [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
>
> tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], dtype=torch.float64)

```py
a = np.ones(5)
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
a=a+1
print(a)
print(b)
```

> [out]:
>
> [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
>
> tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=torch.float64)

Why isn't b changed in the second case ?

Comment: Using `out=a` ensures that the new values are written to the original `a` object.  With `a = a+1`, the result is a new array, which not longer has any connection with the `a` object that was used to create `b`.  This is basic Python behavior.  Some operations modify an object in-place, others create a new object.  `a=....` assigns a new object to the variable `a`; it does not modify what object that was previously assigned to it.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the excellent insight! I've linked the talk by Ned Batchelder in my answer, which also has some visual illustrations of this behavior :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case both `a` and `b` share the same memory (i.e. `b` is a view of `a` or in other words, `b` is pointing to the *(array) value* where `a` is also pointing to) and `out` argument guarantees that the same memory of `a` is updated after the `np.add()` operation is completed.  Whereas in the second case, `a` is a new copy when you do `a = a+1` and `b` is still pointing to the old value of `a`.

Try the second case with:

```
a += 1
```

and observe that both `a` and `b` are indeed updated.

```
In [7]: a = np.ones(5) 
   ...: b = torch.from_numpy(a) 
   ...: a += 1   

In [8]: a  
Out[8]: array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])

In [9]: b 
Out[9]: tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

As [@hpaulj aptly pointed out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310080/what-is-the-logic-behind-this-assignment/58310150#comment102981772_58310080), when we do `a = a+1`, a new object is created and `a` would now point to this new (array) object instead of the old one, which is still pointed to by `b`. And this is the reason the (array) *value* of `b` is not updated.

---

To understand this behavior a bit better, you might wanna refer the excellent article by Ned Batchelder about [how names are bind to values in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)

Comment: I don't know exactly what `torch` is doing with `from_numpy`.  `view` is a specific `numpy` term, referring to a new array object that shares the underlying data buffer.  That could be the case with `torch`, or it could be that `a` is an attribute of `b`.  In any case that link does carry over when a new array is assigned to `a`.

Comment: @hpaulj `torch.from_numpy()` just reads from numpy nd-array and converts it to a torch tensor. However, both the tensor and numpy array share the same memory. So, changes in one will be reflected in the other.

Comment: `a+=1` is actually equal to `a.__iadd__()`, I guess numpy implement this method to inplace muate the `a`, that's why `a+=1` will change the `b` as well.